# Setting base in "New Branch" button in Issues

Tags: git, gitlab

When using the `New Branch` button inside an Issue it currently creates a new branch based on, I believe, the default branch (in my case master). Is there any way I can modify the root branch for this newly created branch? I'd like the newly created branch to be based off `dev` not `master`.

I'd like to avoid solutions that require me to change the default branch.

My current structure is:

```
    issue-branch     lots of changes
-----|--------------------|-------------|
    master                             dev
```

Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
                   lots of changes   issue-branch
-----|--------------------|-------------|
    master                             dev
```

I've tried many combinations of the rebase command but each one manages to include the `lots-of-changes` branch. I'd like `issue-branch` to be based off `dev`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want:

```
$ git rebase --onto dev master issue-branch
```

It will base `issue-branch` onto your `dev` branch. It will however only modify your local repository but that may be all you need.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to do the trick. It still keeps all the commits that occurred between `lots-of-changes` and `dev` in the changelog when pushing `issue-branch`.

Comment: What `changelog` are you talking about?